# Items displaying only from recyclerview and not from top of the items android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using nested scrollview. Inside the nested scrollview,
I have two title (Text and button)
and then below another text
then followed by recyclerview below the layout. 
Then below the recyclerview, there is two edittext and submit button.

Structure looks like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Profile icon-->
        <include layout="@layout/common_profile_layout" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ringkasan Aktifitas"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dafatar_filter"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_change_day"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Pilih Tanggal"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:text="06/13/2017"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
        </LinearLayout>

    //here is recyclerview where loading items.

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite" />
    //here below recyclerview, another edittext with buttons

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/edit_retailer_light_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Laporan Via"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sms_rel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sms_icon"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mark_white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sms_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sms_icon"
                        android:text="SMS" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtSms"
                        android:layout_width="222dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sms_text"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border_curve"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="+62"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rel_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/email_icon"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mark_white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_icon"
                        android:text="Email" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailSms"
                        android:layout_width="222dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_text"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border_curve"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="bejo@gmail.com"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                        android:layout_width="148dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/curve_corner"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Kirim"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But problem is, when I launch, it always displays only from recycler list  when there is more items and it's not displaying from top of recycler view items ie from above recyclerview layouts (titles).

In code,

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // i used only this.. 
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

***recycler_item_rows.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_tag" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="Sell in"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="Selli Cell"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12/11/2017 1.30"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly correct my mistake to display from top.

Here is my output:

[image]

Where it's not displaying from top. And I need to manually scroll to top.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code to main LinearLayout `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`